# Using modulefinder in python 2.7 to discover dependencies in a pyd file

Tags: python, python-2.7, module

I am trying to load a module from a .pyd file I have downloaded from a GitHub repo.  I am running python in the directory with the .pyd file and references to other files in the directory work, so I think the problem isn't a path issue.  Other files in the GitHub show how the module is loaded by that author, so it isn't a naming problem, either.

When I attempt to load module XYZ from XYZ.pyd I get the following error:

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Searching this error tells me that the problem is likely that XYZ.pyd depends on another DLL that I don't have, so I want to trace dependency.  I'm using modulefinder, which is part of the python standard library.

When I try to run modulefinder on the module in XYZ.pyd, I get the following error:

> TypeError: compile() expected string without null bytes

Search results for this error are mostly about JSON, which I'm not sure have anything to do with this problem.  I can get modulefinder to work on ordinary .py files that I have written myself.

My questions are: is it generally possible to use modulefinder on a .pyd file, and if so, is the syntax different from the the usage [given in the manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/modulefinder.html).  More specifically, how do I use modulefinder to see the dependencies on a .pyd file?

Comment: Pretty sure you can't use modulefinder on a .pyd (it says it works on "scripts", which a .pyd is not).  Have you *installed* the package you're trying to use, or just copied its files somewhere?

Comment: Just copied it.

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't install it?  You could also look at the `setup.py` to see what dependencies are listed there.

Comment: I didn't install it because there are no setup.py or other installation scripts.  The author compiles it in Virtual Studio, which I don't have, and uses it as the .pyd file.